# How to CHMOD all folders in folder mac?

Tags: macos, chmod

is there a way to execute chmod(777) on all subfolders in the folder "Folder"? Thanks

Comment: I hope you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use `find` for this:

```
find Folder -type d -exec chmod 0777 {} +
```

Answer (score 5):

If you already are in the parent folder of "Folder" you can run `chmod -R 777 "Folder"`

The `-R` option will tell chmod to do it Recursively.

Comment: This will set the executable bit on all files though, not just folders, which might not be what OP wants.